# Regex Email Validator with Domain specified

Tags: asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I want email validator with specific domains where for example:

```
asdf@asdf.asdf invalid
test@test.co.in  valid
test@test.com  valid
test@test..com   invalid
test.@.test.com   invalid
```

So If i specify "asdf" in my regex expression then it can also be validated.

Comment: I tried, Dim rx As New Regex("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below one

```
\w+@\w+(\.[a-z]{1,3})+$
```

Below is the change as requested.

```
\w+@\w+.(biz|com|au)$
```

Comment: Ya. You are right. Corrected the answer now. Thank You.

Comment: But what if I want to allow "asdf" as domain name.

Comment: like::  I want to allow only email address which ends with test@test.com, test@test.biz, test@test.co.au -- but in future If i add another domain at end like "co.in" then it should allow.

Comment: Something REGEX like   ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$    but it is not working to me..

Comment: Do you want to validate for .com  .biz  .au only ??

Comment: yes for now I want to allow for limited domains. But as per changes in regex I can add more domain in regex to validate in future.